# recursively count lines in files, group by file extension

Tags: bash, awk, sed, find, pipe

## Question

I have a git repository full of files, mostly text.

I want to know that there are

- `n` lines of code in files ending in `.py`
- `m` lines of code in files ending in `.md`
- `o` lines of code in files ending in `.yaml`
- `p` lines of code in files **with no extension**
- etc

Notes:

- I want this to be recursive, checking inside folders
- I want to exclude the `.git` directory in the top level folder
- I want to ignore binary files is possible (noting that I have some text files with no extension, and some binary files with no extension)
- I want to be case insensitive. Group `.csv` with `.CSV`
- I want to ignore empty (or only whitespace) lines
- If there's a file like `myfile.yaml.j2` I do not care whether it's counted in the `.j2` group or `.yaml.j2`.

Comment: What about empy/blank lines? do they count too?

Comment: I want to exclude them. The solution I wrote below includes them. I thought there were options to pass to `wc` for this, but I can't see them.

Comment: Utility for counting lines of code is `cloc`(https://linux.die.net/man/1/cloc). Study the manual and see, what it offers. It will probably not fulfill all the requirements you have, but maybe you will find cloc output informative, and you will find out that it is what you need.

Comment: Could you say that you want to ignore all hidden directories, or just .git?

Comment: Ah yes, all hidden directories would be nice

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
find ./ -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -exec wc -l {} + |
    awk '{print tolower($0)}' |
    sed -e '$ d' | 
    sed -e "s#/.*/##g" |
    sed -e "s/\./ \./g" |
    awk '
        { if ( NF <= 2 ) { count["none"] += $1 } else { count[$NF] += $1 } }
        { next }
        END { for (group in count) printf("%d%s%s\n", count[group], OFS, group) }
    ' |
    sort -n
```

Broken down:

- `find ./` find objects under this directory, recursively
- `-not -path "./.git/*"` excluding `.git`
- `-type f` files not directories
- `-exec wc -l {} +` for each file, run the word count utility (`wc`). 
  This includes empty lines, so doesn't meet all of the question's requirements.
- `awk '{print tolower($0)}'` make lowercase
- `sed -e '$ d'` delete the last line, which is the sum of lines over all files
- `sed -e "s#/.*/##g"` remove the path of the file, e.g., `a/something.egg/blah` should count as no extension, not `.egg/blah` extension
- `sed -e "s/\./ \./g"` search/replace `.` with  `.`,
  so the file extension is its own word
- `awk '{ if ( NF <= 2 ) { count["none"] += $1 } else { count[$NF] += $1 } } { next } END { for (group in count) printf("%d%s%s\n", count[group], OFS, group) }'` this is a big one. 
  `awk` is powerful, but not super clear

  - `count` is a dictionary
  - `if (NF <= 2)` if there are fewer than 3 'words', i.e., there is no extension
  - `count["none"] += $1` increment an element in the dictionary, key is string literal `none`, increment it by adding the number of lines in this file, which is the first word, which is `$1`
  - `count[$NF] += $1` increment an element in the dictionary,
    key is `$NF` (the last word in the line), which is the extension,
    by `$1` (the first word in the line), which is the number of lines in this file
  - `{ next }` repeat for all lines
  - `for (group in count)` a `for` loop, inline
  - `printf(...)` format the output string
    as `number extension`;
    e.g., `123 .abc` (if there are 123 lines in files ending with `.abc`)
- `sort -n` sort the results in ascending order;
  `-n` means sort as a number, not string

Comment: You don't need `{next}` in your `awk` script as that's implied

Comment: `-not` is not an operator supported by `find`. I guess that you intended to use `!`.

Comment: I tweaked this a little bit for my use because I found for a large repository the totals were getting printed intermittently (and not only the last line) which messed up the 'none' counts.
`
find ./ -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -exec wc -l {} + |
  awk '{print tolower($0)}' |
  sed -e "s#/.*/##g" |
  sed -e "s/\./ \./g" |
  awk '
  { if ( $2 == "total" ) {
    count["total"] += $1
  } else if ( NF <= 2 ) {
    count["<no-file-extension>"] += $1
  } else { count[$NF] += $1 } }
  { next }
  END { for (group in count) printf("%d%s%s,", count[group], OFS, group) }
  '

Comment: Please note that for folders with many files the first step will output multiple `nnnnn total` rows and removing the last row is not enough. This will inflate the number of lines for files with no extension.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, and my tests are good, I propose this (assuming you want to skip hidden directories and files, tell me if that's not the case):

```bsh
shopt -s globstar

declare -A arr
for f in test/**; do
  # if a directory, skip
  [[ -d "$f" ]] && continue
  lines=0
  # strip the extension
  ext="${f##*.}"
  # convert it to lowercase
  ext="${ext,,}"
  # if no dot in the name, extension is "empty"
  [[ ! $(basename "$f") =~ \. ]] && ext="empty"
  # count the lines
  lines=$(wc -l "$f"| cut -d' ' -f1)
  # if lines equals to 0, skip
  [[ $lines -eq 0 ]] && continue
  # append the number of line to the array
  lines=$(( "${arr[$ext]}"+$lines ))
  arr[$ext]=$lines 
done

# loop over the array
for n in ${!arr[@]}; do
  echo "files $n: total lines ${arr[$n]}"
done
```

Output (from my example files):

```
files yaml: total lines 3
files md: total lines 3
files empty: total lines 4
files csv: total lines 6
files py: total lines 5
```

Comment: It looks good, but I get `bash: ""+23 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is """+23 ")`. Are you using bash? Do I have to invoke like `. script.sh` or just normal `./script.sh`?

Comment: @falsePockets For now (I deleted al my tests files),  try with the line `[[ ! -z "${arr[$ext]}" ]] && lines=$(( "${arr[$ext]}"+$lines ))`

Comment: I will recreate the files and let you know

Answer (score 1):

I broke things up into functions to try to make it easier to understand:

```
#!/bin/bash

# For the next two functions, we will use "-print0", which will print out \0 instead of \n.
# This will help prevent whitespace problems when piping the filenames into xargs.

find_extension()
{
    find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2" -print0 2>/dev/null
}

find_no_extension()
{
    find "$1" -type f -regex '^.*/[^.]+$' -print0 2>/dev/null
}

concat_files()
{
    xargs -0 cat
}

delete_empty_lines()
{
    sed -E '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
}

line_count_of_files()
{
    concat_files | delete_empty_lines | wc -l
}

print_usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 [EXTENSION]... [SEARCH_DIRECTORY]";
}

NUMBER_OF_EXTENSIONS=$(($# - 1))
SEARCH_DIR="${*: -1}"

if [ $# -lt 2 ];
then
    echo "Not enough parameters.";
    print_usage;
    exit 1;
fi

if ! [ -d "$SEARCH_DIR" ];
then
    echo "$SEARCH_DIR does not exist, or is not a directory."
    print_usage;
    exit 1;
fi

for EXTENSION in "${@:1:$NUMBER_OF_EXTENSIONS}";
do
    printf ".$EXTENSION: %s\n" $(find_extension "$SEARCH_DIR" "$EXTENSION" | line_count_of_files)
done


printf "No extension: %s\n" $(find_no_extension "$SEARCH_DIR" | line_count_of_files)
```

This is more of a generic script that lets you specify arbitrary file extensions to search for. It will always search for files with no extension though.

You should save this into a file, give it executable permission, and put it in your PATH. Let's say you name it count_lines.sh. You can call it like this: `count_lines.sh py md yaml ~/Code`. This will search in the directory `~/Code` for files ending in `.py`, `.md`, and `.yaml`, as well as files without an extension at all. You can choose any number of extensions to search for, just make sure you have at least one.

Comment: `xargs -0` is non-portable, `find -exec +` however is

Comment: @schily wasn't aware of that. If you know how to fix it to use the portable solution, please make an edit.

Comment: Probably by using arguments with the command, given to the functions in case you like to use functions.